# Any alternatives with Global Variables? I don't want to use Global Variables in phpunit testing

Tags: php, json, phpunit, scope, global

I'm using phpunit to create some tests and I ran into a small problem. I created a `$json` string outside the class and I'm using it inside the test functions in order to avoid repetitive variable declarations since there will be dozens of other tests using the same `$json` string.

Now I've been reading over how we shouldn't be using global variables as it can cause difficulties in maintainability in codes so I'm trying to figure out another way to run this test.

I thought about creating parameters for the function to accept but these functions are being run automatically when I run phpunit.

Here is my code:

```
$json = '{ 
                "name": "John", 
                "age": "22", 

             }';

    $data= json_decode($json, true);
    $name = $data['name'];
    $age = $data['age'];


 class UserTest extends TestCase {




 public function testCreateUserName(){
    global $json;
    global  $name;

    $this->call('POST', 'user', array(), array(), array(), $json);

    $this->assertFalse($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

    $decodedOutput = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

    $this->assertEquals($name, $decodedOutput->name, 'Name Input was Incorrect');
    $this->assertResponseStatus(201);


}

}
```

My question is, what's another alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your data in  the `setUp()` method?

Example:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

  private $data;
  private $json;
  private $name;
  private $age;

  public function setUp() {
    $this->json = '{ 
                "name": "John", 
                "age": "22", 

             }';
    $this->data = json_decode($this->json, true);
    $this->name = $this->data['name'];
    $this->age = $this->data['age'];
  }

  public function testCreateUserName(){
      $this->call('POST', 'user', array(), array(), array(), $this->json);

      $this->assertFalse($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

      $decodedOutput = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

      $this->assertEquals($this->name, $decodedOutput->name, 'Name Input was Incorrect');
      $this->assertResponseStatus(201);
  }  
}
```

See this link for more information:

http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/fixtures.html

Comment: For some weird reason, when I add a `setUp()` method, it throws errors when I test for my `call('GET, 'route');`

Comment: Whats your `TestCase` look like? Maybe your over-riding something important? I assume `TestCase` itself inherits from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `setUp()` method that is called by PHPUnit before performing each test to initialize a class variable.

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $json;
    protected $name;
    protected $age;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->json = '{"name":"John","age":22}';
        $data = json_decode($this->json);
        $this->name = $data['name'];
        $this->age = $data['age'];
    }

    public function testCreateUserName()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

There is also a symmetrical method `teardown()` that is called after each test, though it is rare that you would need to define this method.

Check out the PHPUnit manual page on [Fixtures](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/fixtures.html) for more information. I'd recommend reviewing the manual further for information on how you can make tests depend on each other or have one test provide data to another test.

Comment: As I mentioned above in the previous answer, whenever I write a `setUp()` method, it screws up my tests for some reason. I always get an `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object` error but when I remove the `setUp()` method, everything magically works again.

Comment: Did you write some code in TestCase that calls `call_user_func_array()`? What does your `setUp()` method look like?